# Which version of Rails should I use

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm looking to build a web interface for an existing Ruby app and I'm trying to figure out which version of Rails to use - the latest current version 2.3 or the soon-to-be-released version 3.0.

The reasons for using 2.3 are pretty straightforward: it's the current version and it's stable.

My reasons for considering 3.0 are:

- My app uses Ruby 1.9 and Rails 2.3 does not seem to support Ruby 1.9
- Rails 3.0 is supposedly a major rework of the framework.  If I'm starting a new project now I figure I may as well do it 'right' the first time rather than have to migrate it when I'm ready to move to Rails 3.0.

Is 3.0's feature set really so much better?  Is it stable enough for use or am I only asking for trouble?  Anyone have any idea how hard it will be to migrate to 3.0 from 2.3?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rails3 has already been released.
Using it in production now.
Most plugins have been updated for it.
Pros: Speed, new Active Record interface, routes, mailer, more semantic, better integration with Rack.

The list goes on and on.

The key would be that Rails 3 is pretty debugged/tested at this point and ready for production use.

Comment: Rails 3.0 stable isn't actually out yet - it's only been RC since 26th July.

Comment: But will be shortly. 1) if your webapp is very small and simple, RC should be stable enough 2) if you are developing bigger app, it takes time, so stable Rails 3 will be released before you will manage to finish it

Answer (score 0):

As per stability Rails 2.3.5 is good with Ruby 1.8.7. Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9.1 are out, but have not had extensive testing for stability. For the sake of stability use the combination of Rails 2.3.5 and Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: Latest stable version is 2.3.8.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of timeframe are you looking at?

You may want to read [this thread](http://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/213412) to see what some Rails individuals think about communicating progress with Rails 3. :(

Answer (score 0):

Rails 3 has since been released: [Rails 3.0: It's ready!](http://weblog.rubyonrails.org/2010/8/29/rails-3-0-it-s-done)